# Invoke React component from an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs

I have a react application and I have a bundle.js file generated through webpack which has all the code for that application.

Now I have a separate dotnet application. I want to render the top level 'App' component of my react application in this dotnet application.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the markup for the dotnet application you should be able to include the bundle.js file in a `<script>` tag and mount your react app to a specified element with an `id` attribute.

Example JS (in your bundle.js file):

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('divParent'))
```

Example HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='divParent'></div>
  <script src='http://{yourdomain}/bundle.js' />
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already doing that, but the component never gets rendered. It says App is undefined.

Comment: `code`<script src="<path>/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(App, { description: 'World' }, null),
            document.getElementById('divParent')
        );
        
    });
</script>
<div id="divParent">

Comment: Try only having the `<script>` tag with the bundle.js file, not the other `<script>` tag with jQuery. If the bundle.js file targets the div with `ReactDOM` with id `divParent`, it should work. See my edit..

Comment: The problem is I have to pass the id from my dotnet application as it will be dynamically generated.